# TiKZ |- operator doesn't work

Tags: tikz-pgf

Currently I'm learning TiKZ and was following the "Karl drawing unit circle for his students" example. When I got to the point where we draw the sine line, the manual said we could use

```
\draw[red,very thick] (30:1cm |- 0,0)
```

I prefered this to

```
\draw[red,very thick] (30:1cm) -- +(0, -0.5)
```

as it relies on a specific value and is not very general. However, the latter works (draws a nice red sine line) but the former doesn't. How can I resovle this?

Thanks in advance?

Comment: It might help to see where you actually want to use this command, because maybe there might be a more appropriate way to approach the same case.

Comment: I think what you want is `\draw[red,very thick] (30:1cm) -- (30:1cm |- 0,0);`. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: "Does not work" does *not* have a meaning. If you get an error you should *post the error*. If you get an unexpected output you should write both the wrong output you get and the expected output.  The next time you have a question review all your "does not work" expressions and replace them with appropriate descriptions of *what* "does not work" and *how* it "is not working".

Comment: I mean, it doesn't draw the same line as the 2nd command. Anyway this is resolved now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described in the manual, `(30:1cm |- 0,0)` is a coordinate straight down from the coordinate `(30:1cm)`. What you have so far is one of the coordinates, so you need to supply the other.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\clip (-0.1,-0.2) rectangle (1.1,0.75); 
\draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4); 
\draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
\draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
\draw[red,very thick] (30:1cm) -- (30:1cm |- 0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, so it specifies a coordinate - not a line. Yes, this works.